# App crashes while while creating SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

I'm a new developer and a facing a problem while trying to create a database. 
The app runs well when the specific code line is missing.
What am I doing wrong?

And another question: how can i acsses the database from a fragment???

Thanks!

```
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    // it crashes when I add this line

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

LOGCAT:

```
04-15 18:58:42.034: E/Trace(2497): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-15 18:58:42.178: D/AndroidRuntime(2497): Shutting down VM
04-15 18:58:42.178: W/dalvikvm(2497): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa630a288)
04-15 18:58:42.194: E/AndroidRuntime(2497): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 18:58:42.194: E/AndroidRuntime(2497): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.craftyonhand.www/com.craftyonhand.www.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-15 18:58:42.194: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
04-15 18:58:42.194: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
04-15 18:58:42.194: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
04-15 18:58:42.194: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
04-15 18:58:42.194: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-15 18:58:42.194: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-15 18:58:42.194: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-15 18:58:42.194: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 18:58:42.194: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-15 18:58:42.194: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-15 18:58:42.194: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-15 18:58:42.194: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-15 18:58:42.194: E/AndroidRuntime(2497): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-15 18:58:42.194: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:215)
04-15 18:58:42.194: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at com.craftyonhand.www.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:14)
04-15 18:58:42.194: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-15 18:58:42.194: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
04-15 18:58:42.194: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
04-15 18:58:42.194: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
04-15 18:58:42.194: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     ... 11 more
04-15 18:59:13.598: I/Process(2497): Sending signal. PID: 2497 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Where is the database? In the fragment you are creating? Please post the error.

Comment: 04-15 13:44:11.294: E/Trace(971): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Thats the ERROR I'm Getting in logcat.

Comment: you need to post whole stacktrace. one line won't do any good

Answer (score 2):

You are initializing it too early. Move the init code to `onCreate()` where the activity is a valid context.

Comment: Great! that worked!!
Can you also inform me on how do I access the database from fragments?

Comment: For db ease of use, consider using SQLiteOpenHelper instead of directly opening the db.

Comment: Thnaks, I will take a look at this. But just wondring how to adress the database from the fragment. I've declared the db in the activity and it does not recognize it on the fragment..